# Using jQuery's scrollTo & onAfterFirst to redevelop a website

Tags: jquery, iframe, html, scrollto

So here's where I'm stuck. I'm trying to redevelop my internship companies website (www.20nine.com) from the flash/flex monster it is now into jQuery with the same functionality.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

At those links, in the "Options" section, click on "onAfterFirst". This is the exact transition I need but with some tweaks.

The code bit on that site looks like this:

```
    $('#options-onAfterFirst').click(function(){

        reset_o(); $paneOptions.scrollTo( 'li:eq(15)', 1600, { 

            queue:true,

            onAfterFirst:function(){

                $('#options-message').text('Got there horizontally!');

            },

            onAfter:function(){

                $('#options-message').text('Got there vertically!');

            }

        });
```

What I want to do is create a site that uses a 3x3 grid of Divs, and change those "onAfter:function's" to load each div's (or iFrame) content when it lands. Currently, that code also forces the content to display in one frame, where as we need each div/iframe to display full screen, independent of the users browser window size.

Here is an image to illustrate it:

[image: illustration]

The gray squares would each "page", I guess these would have to be iFrames. 
The purple line would be the main wrapper holding the entirety of the site together.
The blue line designates how I want the browser to recognize the full screen aspect, and move through a quick full screen image, then onto the next Content page.

In the scrollTo code library, the one I'm working with is labeled "Diagonal" (This is apparently necessary in order to pull of the two movement effect)

In my search for help, I've read that REMOVING this line of code will allow the full screen utility, but I haven't verified this (I can barely get mine to function at the moment)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //call the resizePanel function
    resizePanel();
});
```

According to the person, this should make the div full screen on window resize.

I'm definitely messing up where I need to inject the code, and how to properly set up the 3x3 div/iframe combo mess (thats such a weird site structure for what Im used to)

Any tips on how to engineer this monster?